# Big O notation, running time for algorithm

Tags: runtime, big-o

I am trying to determine a bound on the running time,
I think I understand it but, may be double coutning.

```
y=0
for i = 1 to n do (1)
  for j= i to n do (2)
    if i == j then (3)
       k=n
       while k > 0 do (4)
         y = y + 1
         k = k/3
```

I figured,

(1) Loops n times 
(2) Loops n/2 times
(3) Loops n times
(4) Loops log<sub>3</sub>n times

This would be n(n<sup>2</sup>log<sub>3</sub>n)/2 .
It seems too complicated,

Any points in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does (2) loop n/2 times?  (3) is not a loop, it's an `if` statement. (4) looks asymptotic; depending on the data type of K, it might loop for a very, very long time.

Comment: Okay, then it is only true once per loop of the for statement, which will be n times.

Comment: (1) will always loop n times.  (2) will always loop n times.  (3) will *execute* when `i == j`, which will happen n times. (4) will loop until k is 0, which is asymptotic towards 0 unless k is an integer and you're throwing away the remainder.

Comment: I realize I had a typo, (2) is from i to n, thats where I got the n/2 from.
k is an integer, and rounds down to the nearest integer.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze this, first pull the loop dependent tests out of the loops:

```
y = 0
for i = 1 to n do
  j = i
  (* i == j is true, no need for if test *)
    k = n
    while k > 0 do
      y = y + 1
      k = k/3
  for j = i+1 to n do
    (* i == j is false *)
    nothing
```

Then get rid of the nested j loop that does nothing, leaving you with 2 nested loops:

```
y = 0
for i = 1 to n do
  k = n
  while k > 0 do
    y = y + 1
    k = k/3
```

When computing big-O notation, you ignore constant factors, so different bases on the log are irrelevant.  So assuming `/` is truncating integer division, you get **O**(*n* log *n*)